# Opening times in Django with less hit on db

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a structure to show the opening times from food companies, ordered by "open" status. But I don't know how can I get the informations on my template. For example:

```
#models.py
class Company(Model):
    #... fields ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s'%self.title
```

Here I'll store all times and days.

```
class OpeningHours(Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Horário de Abertura")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Horários de Abertura")
        unique_together = ('company', 'weekday')
    company = ForeignKey(Company, related_name="opening_times", verbose_name=_(u"Empresa"))
    weekday = IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, verbose_name=_(u"Dia da Semana"))
    fromHour = TimeField(verbose_name=_(u"Abre ás:"), null=True, blank=True)
    toHour = TimeField(verbose_name=_(u"Fecha ás:"), null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s (%s - %s)" % (self.company, self.weekday, self.fromHour, self.toHour)
```

And then I'm catching all the companies just like that on my views:

```
#views.py - This is how I'm processing the views
companies       = sorted(Company.objects.filter(category__food=True).order_by('?')[0:4], key=lambda c: c.show_open(), reverse=True)
```

So, now the problem are in template, I need someway to catch this informations:

## template.html - This is what I need to do on template

```
{% for company in companies %}
    {% if company.open %}
        OPEN
    {% else %}
        CLOSED
    {% endif %}
    <!-- I need to know when it's today, when it's tomorrow or when it's another day -->
    {% ifequal company.open today %}
        Next day will open is today at {{ company.next_time_open }}
    {% ifequal company.open another_day %}
        Next day will open is Sunday at {{ company.next_time_open }}
    {% else %}
        Wait, it's open right now from 22h till 00h
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why dont you order it with your sql query? why are you sorting the result in python?

Comment: Joran, the problem is how can I get these informations withou hit the db too many times, do you have some suggestion? I need to catch the informations just like I put in my template.html but I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, doing `.order_by('?')` is randomizing your queryset, which you are then sorting in Python. Ordering randomly causes the query to take more process time on the database side, and then sorting it in Python is its own additional process time. I would consider ordering your queryset using Django's methods, instead, by specifying the field(s) you want to order by in `.order_by()`.

Secondly, one way to reduce database hits is to use `.select_related()` on the queryset. This will include related models in the queryset under a single SQL statement, so that later calls to the related models in the template don't cause new database hits.

Third, there is a lot of code in your different sections that reference fields and methods that I assume you've defined, but without seeing them directly, I can't make a judgment on what exactly you're doing. It is not possible at this time to give you a more direct answer.